# What comic book story is referred to in the Infinity War trailer "the click of his fingers"?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, avengers-infinity-war

Ok so talking to my friend after school on Friday and he said that when Gamora said

> "he can end the universe with the click of fingers"

According to him it was a reference to the comics and he said he read it from a Marvel page on Instagram.

My question is:
Is it a reference to the comics and if yes, which comic is it referring to?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it most likely is a reference. Marvel does find ways to sneak in connections.

**EDIT:**

The comic issue ***Thanos: Infinity Gauntlet*** was a six issue story-arc published in the 90's. In issue # 3 (I guess), Thanos snaps his fingers and instantly kills half of the living beings in existence. He does this as a tribute to Mistress Death in hopes of gaining her favour. It could most likely be a reference to this (image below from the comics).

[image]

Comment: He wasn't just wiping out a planet.  He was fulfilling his promise to Death for her assistance in finding the gems, that promise being to wipe out half the life in the universe.

Comment: @suchiuomizu I read it about 5-6 years ago. Sorry for the mistakes. I have made the necessary corrections now. Should do fine. Thanks for pointing it out :)